# Extracting audio from video

Tags: android-emulator

We are involved in a project on extracting audio from a stored video and facing difficulties in the extraction.

Is it possible to extract audio from a video in andriod eclipse environment?
Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder), you'll find everything you need from here:

http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php

Hope it helps

Comment: Look at its license, it's GPL - meaning you'll have to open source your application